# Sqoop + Postgresql: how to prevent quotes around table name

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to import a table from Postgresql to a Parquet file on HDFS.

Here is what I do:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect "jdbc:postgresql://pg.foo.net:5432/bar" \
    --username user_me --password $PASSWORD \
    --table foo.bar \
    --target-dir /user/me/bar \
    --as-parquetfile
```

and I get

```
INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM "foo.bar" AS t LIMIT 1
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "foo.bar" does not exist
```

`SELECT t.* FROM "foo.bar" AS t LIMIT 1` does not work indeed, but `SELECT t.* FROM foo.bar AS t LIMIT 1` does. So the problem is that table name is quoted. I tried supplying `--table` argument different ways, but with no effect.

How do I work it around?

## EDIT

As the docs you linked state, there is a `--schema` argument. For some reason it is not mentioned in `sqoop help import`.

Another weird thing is that

```
--table bar --schema foo
```

still does not work, but

```
--table bar -- --schema foo
```

does.

Anyway, it works now. Thanks for linking the relevant docs section!

Comment: The docs explain it as follows:  `If the argument -- is given on the command-line, then subsequent arguments are sent directly to the underlying tool.  For example, the following adjusts the character set used by mysqldump:` So it seems the --schema is given to pg_dump: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html And that means you could use the rest of pg_dump controls...Maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name is `bar`, `foo` is the name of the schema.
According to the [docs](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_schema_support_2) you should do it like:

```
sqoop import \
    (...)
    --table bar \
    --schema foo
    (...)
```

Comment: (upvoted) That is almost the solution, thanks! (I edited my answer with details)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_schema_support_2) you need to specify the schema separately:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect "jdbc:postgresql://pg.foo.net:5432/bar" \
    --username user_me --password $PASSWORD \
    --table bar \
    --schema foo \
    --target-dir /user/me/bar \
    --as-parquetfile
```

Comment: (upvoted) That is almost the solution, thanks! (I edited my answer with details)

Comment: It seems that @Jakub answered a few seconds before you, so I'll accept his answer.